# Column Freeze or Fixed Column in datatable

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible to freeze first 3 columns of Primefaces' data table?

I'm using Primefaces 3.1

Comment: This is not possible as of today. Please check http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=366

Comment: Any workarounds to achieve the same? Tried jquery's freeze, but it breaks teh filter.

Comment: You can contribute to the funding of this feature for PrimeFaces. http://www.primefaces.org/funding.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primefaces does not support fixed columns right now.

Jquery fixed column was used to achieve the same. Reference : http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/

Example:

```js
var oTable2 = $(primfacesDataTableId).find('table').dataTable({
                "sScrollX" : "100%", //Scroll
                "sScrollY" : "180",
                "bAutoWidth" : false,
                "bScrollCollapse" : true,
                "bPaginate" : false,
                "bSort" : false,
                "sInfo" : "",
                "sInfoEmpty" : ""
            });

var oFC = new FixedColumns(oTable2, {
                    "iLeftColumns" : 4, //Freezed first for columns
                    "sHeightMatch" : "auto",
                    "iLeftWidth" : 405
                });
```

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: Any idea to make this run in a primefaces treetable? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722143/primefaces-treetable-frozen-columns)

Comment: Hi Shikha, when I try to create oTable2 gives me this error Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'. Any Idea??? Thx

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using Primefaces 4.1 or above, this feature is now implemented (it took four years from the first request, by the way):

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=366

You can play with the horizontal scrolling in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml).