# Primefaces TreeTable frozen columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treetable, frozen-columns

is it possible to make the first two columns of a primefaces treetable frozen?

This is my TreeTable:

```
<h:form id="mmvUebersicht">
    <p:treeTable id="massnahmenUebersichtTable" value="#{mmvOrganisationseinheitenTreeHandler.root}" var="_tree"
        selection="#{mmvOrganisationseinheitenTreeHandler.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500">

        <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{mmvOrganisationseinheitenTreeHandler.onNodeExpand}" />
        <ui:remove>
            <p:ajax event="select" update=":mmvUebersichtEastForm" listener="#{mmvOrganisationseinheitenTreeHandler.onNodeSelect}" />
        </ui:remove>

        <p:column headerText="#{labels.abteilung}" style="width:250px">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{_tree.id} #{_tree.shortNameName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{labels.funktion}" style="width:150px">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{structureNodeHandler.getAttributeCommentByAttributeType(_tree, 'Leitung')}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{labels.verantwortlich}" style="width:150px">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{mmvHelper.getUserByRacf(structureNodeHandler.getAttributeValueByAttributeType(_tree, 'Leitung'))}" />
        </p:column>

        <c:forEach items="#{massnahmenDefintionListHandler.defList}" var="_mass">
            <p:column style="width:50px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{_mass.kurzName}" title="#{mass.name}" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandLink onclick="mmvlayout.show('east')" update=":mmvContentPanelEast :mmvUebersichtEastForm"
                    action="#{mmvHandler.fillUebersichtEastPanel(_tree,_mass)}" rendered="#{massnahmenErfuellungsObjekt.abteilungHasMassnahme(_tree,_mass,true)}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{massnahmenErfuellungsObjekt.bestimmeMassnahmenFaelligkeiten(_tree,_mass,true)}"
                        styleClass="#{massnahmenErfuellungsObjekt.cellColor()} statusBar" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
        </c:forEach>
        <p:column style="width:*"></p:column>
    </p:treeTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Wat do you mean with frozen? So that they can't be collapsed?

Comment: There is a primefaces feature for datatables, which is called "frozen rows" (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFrozenRows.jsf) I would like to do the same with the first two columns.

Comment: Well not out of the box :-) Maybe you can fix the frozen columns with a datatable and fill the rest with a TreeTable?

Comment: The idea is good, but is not possible for me, because I need the treetable. (my data structure is a tree (it is a hierarchy of a company))

Comment: @Kukeltje Is there a way we can achieve this in primefaces tree table with frozen columns?