# PrimeFaces Js integration within an xhtml page

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.5RC. I am having trouble implementing the following JS function to enable me to freeze columns on a dataTable. I'm still new to JS and don't know how I should reference my dataTable id within the Example JS functions below that I found on StackOverflow: [Column Freeze or Fixed Column in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651152/column-freeze-or-fixed-column-in-datatable). Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
var oTable2 = $(primfacesDataTableId).find('table').dataTable({
            "sScrollX" : "100%", //Scroll
            "sScrollY" : "180",
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "bScrollCollapse" : true,
            "bPaginate" : false,
            "bSort" : false,
            "sInfo" : "",
            "sInfoEmpty" : ""
        });

var oFC = new FixedColumns(oTable2, {
                "iLeftColumns" : 4, //Freezed first for columns
                "sHeightMatch" : "auto",
                "iLeftWidth" : 405
            });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select PrimeFaces UI or JSF components using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you refer the Primeface/JSF components from the parent form component.
For Example:

If you have following code:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dataTable id="myTable">
       .....
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Refer your DataTable as:

```
myForm:myTable
```

Or you can get it from Firebug Console in your browser.

While you are referring to the component form **JQuery** use:

```
$("[id='myForm:myTable']")
```