# Apply DataTables.js to p:dataTable primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, datatables

I try to use **DataTables.js** (specifically **FixedColumns**) in one `p:datatable`.
This is my head:

```
<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="titulo">#{bundleComunes.Titulo}</ui:insert></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="#{request.contextPath}/extras/FixedColumns/media/js/FixedColumns.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/media/js/jquery.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"/>
</h:head>
```

and this is my `p:dataTable`

```
<p:dataTable var="row" id="list" value="#{BB.dataTable}" rowStyleClass="#{styleController.colored(row.modificable)}" style="width : 1024px">
        <p:column headerText="#{bundle['id1']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.id1}" title="#{row.id1.descripcion}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{bundle['id2']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.id2}" title="#{row.id2.descripcion}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:columns var="fecha" value="#{BB.lFechaEntradaVigor}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{fecha}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{row.getCoste(fecha)}" styleClass="#{row.modificable &amp;&amp; row.isValido(fecha)?'vigor':''}" style="text-align:right;">
                    <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
```

and this my **js**

```
var oTable2 = $('#list').find('table').dataTable({
            "sScrollX" : "100%", //Scroll
            "sScrollY" : "180",
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "bScrollCollapse" : true,
            "bPaginate" : false,
            "bSort" : false,
            "sInfo" : "",
            "sInfoEmpty" : ""
        });
```

var oFC = new FixedColumns(oTable2, {
                    "iLeftColumns" : 4, //Freezed first for columns
                    "sHeightMatch" : "auto",
                    "iLeftWidth" : 405
                });

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651152/column-freeze-or-fixed-column-in-datatable)  but **js** gives me this error: `Can not get value ' aoColumns ' property : the object is null or undefined` but error is in **FixedColumns.js:83** `"iTableColumns": oDT.fnSettings().aoColumns.length,` `oDT.fnSettings()` is null

Any idea??
THX

Comment: You know that you can use DataTable - Frozen Columns : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableFrozenColumns.jsf;jsessionid=mio06h71euds1sjpqp6z09xzn :) its new...

Comment: But this is in PrimeFaces-5.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my problem are **prependId** must be **false**.

```
<h:form id="idForm" prependId="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
"aoColumns": [
      null
    ]
```

Comment: Maybe your datatable seems to be empty, does it work without Js call ?

Comment: In really error are in **oDT.fnSettings(...) is null**