# DataTable Fixed Column Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable, fixed

i nedd help with fixed column in datatable primefaces. Is it possible to freeze/fixed first 3 columns of Primefaces' data table?

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and GlassFish 3.1.2.2

I read about jquery but i dont know how use it. Someone can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column Freeze or Fixed Column in datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651152/column-freeze-or-fixed-column-in-datatable)

Comment: You can upgrade to PF 4.1 or higher it's already [included](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml)

Comment: Yes, i know but i cant changed the version. i'm working in a business project and is impossible because it would change everything