# can I implement frozen column using primefaces 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

**Hi I want to implement frozen column in my **p:datatable** using **primefaces 4.0** but its not working.can anyone let me know where I am doing wrong. below is my code.**
I used the below link to implement it in my code but its not working for me

[Column Freeze or Fixed Column in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651152/column-freeze-or-fixed-column-in-datatable)

Thanks in advance

group.xhtml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
          <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery('.ui-datatable tbody').sortable();
            });
            var oTable2 = $(primfacesDataTableId).find('table').dataTable({
                "sScrollX" : "100%", //Scroll
                "sScrollY" : "180",
                "bAutoWidth" : false,
                "bScrollCollapse" : true,
                "bPaginate" : false,
                "bSort" : false,
                "sInfo" : "",
                "sInfoEmpty" : ""
            });

var oFC = new FixedColumns(oTable2, {
                    "iLeftColumns" : 4, //Freezed first for columns
                    "sHeightMatch" : "auto",
                    "iLeftWidth" : 405
                });
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <p:dataTable id="primfacesDataTableId" var="sale" value="#{dtGroupView.sales}" scrollable="true" style="width: 250%">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Sales/Profits of Manufacturers
        </f:facet>

        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column rowspan="3" headerText="Manufacturer"/>
                <p:column colspan="7" headerText="Sale Rate" />
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Sales" />
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Profit" />
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="Last Year" sortBy="lastYearProfit"/>
                <p:column headerText="This Year" />
                <p:column headerText="Last Year" />
                <p:column headerText="This Year" />
                <p:column headerText="This Year1" />
                <p:column headerText="This Year2" />
                <p:column headerText="This Year3" />
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <p:column >
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.manufacturer}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column  sortBy="#{sale.lastYearProfit}">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.lastYearProfit}%" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{sale.thisYearProfit}%">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.thisYearProfit}%" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{sale.lastYearSale}">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.lastYearSale}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{sale.thisYearSale}">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.thisYearSale}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column  sortBy="#{sale.lastYearProfit}">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.lastYearProfit}%" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{sale.thisYearProfit}%">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.thisYearProfit}%" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column sortBy="#{sale.lastYearSale}">
            <h:outputText value="#{sale.lastYearSale}">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:columnGroup type="footer">
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right" footerText="Totals:" />
                <p:column footerText="$#{dtGroupView.lastYearTotal}" />

                <p:column footerText="$#{dtGroupView.thisYearTotal}" />
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            Data between 2013-2014
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</html>

GroupView.java

package org.primefaces.showcase.view.data.datatable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Player;
import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Sale;

@ManagedBean(name="dtGroupView")
@ViewScoped
public class GroupView implements Serializable {

    private final static String[] manufacturers;
    private List<Sale> sales;

    private final static String[] playerNames;
    private List<Integer> years;
    private List<Player> players;

    static {        
        manufacturers = new String[10];
        manufacturers[0] = "Apple";
        manufacturers[1] = "Samsung";
        manufacturers[2] = "Microsoft";
        manufacturers[3] = "Philips";
        manufacturers[4] = "Sony";
        manufacturers[5] = "LG";
        manufacturers[6] = "Sharp";
        manufacturers[7] = "Panasonic";
        manufacturers[8] = "HTC";
        manufacturers[9] = "Nokia";
    }

    static {
        playerNames = new String[10];
        playerNames[0] = "Lionel Messi";
        playerNames[1] = "Cristiano Ronaldo";
        playerNames[2] = "Arjen Robben";
        playerNames[3] = "Franck Ribery";
        playerNames[4] = "Ronaldinho";
        playerNames[5] = "Luis Suarez";
        playerNames[6] = "Sergio Aguero";
        playerNames[7] = "Zlatan Ibrahimovic";
        playerNames[8] = "Neymar Jr";
        playerNames[9] = "Andres Iniesta";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sales = new ArrayList<Sale>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sales.add(new Sale(manufacturers[i], getRandomAmount(), getRandomAmount(), getRandomPercentage(), getRandomPercentage()));
        }

        years = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        years.add(2010);
        years.add(2011);
        years.add(2012);
        years.add(2013);
        years.add(2014);

        players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            players.add(new Player(playerNames[i], generateRandomGoalStatsData()));
        }
    }

    public List<Sale> getSales() {
        return sales;
    }

    private int getRandomAmount() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 100000);
    }

    private int getRandomPercentage() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }

    public String getLastYearTotal() {
        int total = 0;

        for(Sale sale : getSales()) {
            total += sale.getLastYearSale();
        }

        return new DecimalFormat("###,###.###").format(total);
    }

    public String getThisYearTotal() {
        int total = 0;

        for(Sale sale : getSales()) {
            total += sale.getThisYearSale();
        }

        return new DecimalFormat("###,###.###").format(total);
    }

    public List<Integer> getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public int getYearCount() {
        return years.size();
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    private Map<Integer,Integer> generateRandomGoalStatsData() {
        Map<Integer,Integer> stats = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            stats.put(years.get(i), getRandomGoals());
        }

        return stats;
    }

    private int getRandomGoals() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50);
    }
}


Sale.java


package org.primefaces.showcase.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Sale implements Serializable {

    private String manufacturer;

    private int lastYearSale;

    private int thisYearSale;

    private int lastYearProfit;

    private int thisYearProfit;

    public Sale() {}

    public Sale(String manufacturer, int lastYearSale, int thisYearSale, int lastYearProfit, int thisYearProfit) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.lastYearSale = lastYearSale;
        this.thisYearSale = thisYearSale;
        this.lastYearProfit = lastYearProfit;
        this.thisYearProfit = thisYearProfit;
    }

    public int getLastYearProfit() {
        return lastYearProfit;
    }

    public void setLastYearProfit(int lastYearProfit) {
        this.lastYearProfit = lastYearProfit;
    }

    public int getLastYearSale() {
        return lastYearSale;
    }

    public void setLastYearSale(int lastYearSale) {
        this.lastYearSale = lastYearSale;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public int getThisYearProfit() {
        return thisYearProfit;
    }

    public void setThisYearProfit(int thisYearProfit) {
        this.thisYearProfit = thisYearProfit;
    }

    public int getThisYearSale() {
        return thisYearSale;
    }

    public void setThisYearSale(int thisYearSale) {
        this.thisYearSale = thisYearSale;
    }
}
```

Comment: But where is your code???

Comment: Hi All I am new user to stackoverflow. getting little problem in using it.I am sorry if anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje. I did not get answer of my question thats why again I asked. I will take care your of words .thanks

Comment: Hi Minhas I just edited my post please have a review once. thank you

Comment: Some basics: jQuery works client-side, you post server side xhtml. Your code is in ONE block, not multiple, correct that. With 2 columns you can also try to simulate this, remove all the others...

Comment: I tried with 2 columns also its not working. is anything wrong in  "var oTable2 " and "var oFC" ?